# Как сделать так, чтобы подключались несколько аккаунтов

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, telegram, telethon

Имеется код, где в tkinter осуществляется вход в аккаунт телеграмм. сначала у нас по нажатию кнопки запускается def auth, после чего запускается асинхрнная функция async def cli из которой уже запускается класс authorisation_account.
Такой вопрос: как можно сделать, чтобы одновременно мог подключить несколько аккаунтов? что бы при указании числа, допустим, 2, создавалось два окна для входа в каждый из аккаунтов?

```
class authorisation_account(tkinter.Toplevel):
        
    def __init__(self, client, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.client = TelegramClient(SESSION, API_ID, API_HASH)
        for i in range(1,3):
            self.cl = client
            self.title('Авторизация аккаунтов')
            self.geometry(SIZE)


            self.label = tkinter.Label(self, text = 'wait a few seconds')
            self.label.grid(row = i, column = 0)

            self.entry = tkinter.Entry(self,)
            self.entry.grid(row = i, column = 1, sticky = tkinter.EW)
            self.entry.bind('<Return>', self.sign_in)

            self.button = tkinter.Button(self, text = '123', command = self.sign_in)
            self.button.grid(row = i, column = 2)

            self.code = None

            self.send_button = tkinter.Button(self, text = 'send message' + str(i), command = self.send_msg,)
            self.send_button.grid(row = i, column = 3,)
            
            asyncio.create_task(self.post_init())


    #async def con(self):
        #await self.client.connect()

    async def post_init(self):
        for i in range(1,3):
            if await self.cl.is_user_authorized():
                self.set_signed_in(await self.cl.get_me())
                
            else:
                # User is not logged in, configure the button to ask them to login
                self.button.configure(text='Sign in')
                self.label.configure(
                    text='Sign in (phone):')


    @callback
    async def sign_in(self, event = None):
        #for i in range(1,3):
        self.label.configure(text = 'working...')
        self.entry.configure(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
        if await self.cl.is_user_authorized():
            await self.cl.log_out()
            self.destroy()
            return
        value = self.entry.get().strip()
        if self.code:
            self.set_signed_in(await self.cl.sign_in(code=value))
        #elif ':' in value:
        #    self.set_signed_in(await self.cl.sign_in(bot_token=value))
        else:
            self.code = await self.cl.send_code_request(value)
            self.label.configure(text='Code:')
            self.entry.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
            self.entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
            self.entry.focus()
            return

    def set_signed_in(self, me):
        """
        Configures the application as "signed in" (displays user's
        name and disables the entry to input phone).
        """
        #for i in range(1,3):
        self.me = me
        self.label.configure(text='Signed in')
        self.entry.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        self.entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        self.entry.insert(tkinter.INSERT, utils.get_display_name(me) + ' ' + me.phone )
        self.entry.configure(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
        self.button.configure(text='Log out')

        #self.chat.focus()

    @callback
    async def send_msg(self, event = None):
        await self.cl.send_message('me', 'hello')

        print('sended')
```

```
    async def cli(interval=0.05):
        for i in range(1,3):
            user = 'user' + str(i)
            client = TelegramClient(user, API_ID, API_HASH)
            try:
                await client.connect()
            except Exception as e:
                print('Failed to connect', e, file=sys.stderr)
                return

            auth = authorisation_account(client)

            try:
                while True:
                    auth.update()
                    await asyncio.sleep(0.05)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                pass
            except tkinter.TclError as e:
                if 'application has been destroyed' not in e.args[0]:
                    raise
            finally:
                await auth.cl.disconnect()

    def auth(self):     
        clien = self.cli()
        asyncio.run(clien)
```